Axios headers get, Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2723)
I get the file name from the content-disposition object in the response header, but typescript gives an error. Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2723)
     const filename = response.headers.get('content-disposition')?.split('"')[1] || 'file';


Also this didnt work
     const filename = response?.headers?.get('content-disposition')?.split('"')[1] || 'file';

Thanks for helping.

In axios, you just do this: response?.headers['content-disposition']

BTW, Do you want make your axios more lightweight, try xior.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/xior @AsrinUtku
and you can use like this in xior.js: response?.headers?.get('content-disposition')
